# Altium doesn't let me place anything on schematic

Tags: altium

When I left click the mouse to place a component, nothing happens. I can't place the components.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EE Stack Exchange.

In many of the cases that I encounter similiar issues is when I have forgotten to activate the licence of Altium.