# Altium problem when components placement

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

When i try to place the components in the schematic in altium, it looks like it is not allowed and the components became transparent as if it is not active

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altium doesn't let me place anything on schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/500181/altium-doesnt-let-me-place-anything-on-schematic)

Comment: Can you show some screenshot of that?

Comment: Are you placing the components from online altium library?

Comment: @aparna https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a84_7tlYt2_xcj-QK_seQBU3d6_FP1c7/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @aparna no, even when i tried to place the GND and VCC The same problem still exists

Comment: Okay. Is the license active?

Comment: @aparna yes, I double checked it yesterday

Comment: Also check out settings of appearance  symbol color and transparency

Comment: @aparna wher can i find this in the preferences?

Comment: Let me see in my pc and tell you

Comment: @aparna ok thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Reinstall the software and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place from altium library, it needs separate license and you can see that symbol and footprint are not available. Alternatively you can use snapeda.com. they have libraries of almost all the devices. You can  download altium format libraries and import it in altium